# Characterization: Automorphisms of $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, affine-varieties

Is there any sort of characterization(/research?) of automorphisms (of varieties) on $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^n$?

(The question came up, as we had to find a "non-trivial" automorphism on $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^2$, so I was wondering about this.)

Comment: It is a huge group. https://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/~slamy/stock/basel_minicours.pdf

Comment: Wow! Thank you!